# What information can be extracted from this system crash trace

Tags: server, 9.04

My ubuntu (jaunty) system crashed recently with this trace. What information can I deduce from this trace? 
I was logged in via ssh, and was trying to connect to a wifi network. ath_tx_start sounds like a function in madwifi driver.
What locations should I search in to find further traces, and is there some place on the net where I can find help on the crash?

EDIT : I have just found that the processor on the machine is a geode processer and does not support PAE, and I have installed the default kernel that comes with ubuntu server (that uses PAE). Could this be causing the crash?

```
[  399.757029] BUG: unable to handle kernel paging request at d0c1510c

[  399.760789] IP: [<d0cb5312>] ath_tx_start+0x1022/0x1440 [ath_pci]

[  399.760789] Oops: 0000 [#1] 

[  399.760789] last sysfs file: /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:0e.0/net/ath0/type

[  399.760789] Dumping ftrace buffer:

[  399.760789]    (ftrace buffer empty)

[  399.760789] Modules linked in: wlan_scan_sta ath_rate_sample ath_pci wlan ath_hal(P) ipv6 lp parport loop evdev pcspkr scx200 ext3 jbd mbcache ide_gd_modr

[  399.760789] 

[  399.760789] Pid: 1918, comm: sshd Tainted: P           (2.6.28-6-386 #20-Ubuntu) 

[  399.760789] EIP: 0060:[<d0cb5312>] EFLAGS: 00010046 CPU: 0

[  399.760789] EIP is at ath_tx_start+0x1022/0x1440 [ath_pci]

[  399.760789] EAX: 00000240 EBX: 00000000 ECX: 0000001c EDX: d0c147e0

[  399.760789] ESI: 00000001 EDI: ce5b7878 EBP: ce45de54 ESP: ce45dd64

[  399.760789]  DS: 007b ES: 007b FS: 0000 GS: 0033 SS: 0068

[  399.760789] Process sshd (pid: 1918, ti=ce45c000 task=cde7cf80 task.ti=ce45c000)

[  399.760789] Stack:

[  399.760789]  00000018 ce45de47 ce45de40 ce45de46 c030caf1 ce45dd94 00000246 c030caf1

[  399.760789]  00000000 ce9569c0 031884a0 00007d2b cee684a0 00000246 ce45ddb0 c0309aec

[  399.760789]  c0340737 00000000 00003fd0 ce0e05d0 ce424000 ce5b6000 ce5b0600 cee6681e

[  399.760789] Call Trace:

[  399.760789]  [<c030caf1>] ? __kfree_skb+0x31/0x80

[  399.760789]  [<c030caf1>] ? __kfree_skb+0x31/0x80

[  399.760789]  [<c0309aec>] ? release_sock+0x7c/0x90

[  399.760789]  [<c0340737>] ? tcp_cleanup_rbuf+0xe7/0x110

[  399.760789]  [<c0309333>] ? sock_common_recvmsg+0x43/0x60

[  399.760789]  [<c030d53c>] ? dev_alloc_skb+0x1c/0x30

[  399.760789]  [<d0cb57fd>] ? ath_mgtstart+0xcd/0x1e0 [ath_pci]

[  399.760789]  [<c030d53c>] ? dev_alloc_skb+0x1c/0x30

[  399.760789]  [<d0c75ff5>] ? ieee80211_getmgtframe+0x65/0x90 [wlan]

[  399.760789]  [<d0c67ab5>] ? ieee80211_send_nulldata+0x115/0x170 [wlan]

[  399.760789]  [<c01403f3>] ? getnstimeofday+0x53/0x100

[  399.760789]  [<d0c657a1>] ? ieee80211_node_timeout+0x2b1/0x300 [wlan]

[  399.760789]  [<c012f28d>] ? run_timer_softirq+0x11d/0x1e0

[  399.760789]  [<d0c654f0>] ? ieee80211_node_timeout+0x0/0x300 [wlan]

[  399.760789]  [<d0c654f0>] ? ieee80211_node_timeout+0x0/0x300 [wlan]

[  399.760789]  [<c012b037>] ? __do_softirq+0x67/0x110

[  399.760789]  [<c01068f9>] ? timer_interrupt+0x29/0x60

[  399.760789]  [<c012b12d>] ? do_softirq+0x4d/0x50

[  399.760789]  [<c012b21d>] ? irq_exit+0x2d/0x40

[  399.760789]  [<c0106221>] ? do_IRQ+0x71/0x90

[  399.760789]  [<c019915d>] ? sys_read+0x3d/0x70

[  399.760789]  [<c01050b3>] ? common_interrupt+0x23/0x30

[  399.760789]  [<c0380000>] ? atm_del_addr+0x130/0x150

[  399.760789] Code: 45 f3 8b 55 b8 8d 04 40 0f b7 44 82 2c 01 c3 eb 9d c7 04 24 2d eb cb d0 e8 ec 92 6d ef 0f 0b eb fe 0f b6 45 f3 8b 55 b8 8d 04 40 <0f> b 

[  399.760789] EIP: [<d0cb5312>] ath_tx_start+0x1022/0x1440 [ath_pci] SS:ESP 0068:ce45dd64

[  399.760789] Kernel panic - not syncing: Fatal exception in interrupt
```

Comment: The following wiki page should provide some help: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Debugging

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the problem was in the PAE. I was using soekris 4801 box, which has a geode processor without PAE extension, but the default kernel installed uses PAE extension, leading to kernel panics when i started using wifi.

The problem was solved by installing and using the generic kernel via the package linux-image-generic. ALternatively, one can recompile and install the kernel from source without PAE enabled.

Comment: Just waiting for 24 hrs to be over after posting the answer.